# AS3 How do I make these objects loop endlessly?

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, actionscript

Here is my code so far, I am trying to create a top down car game and here is the code I have so far, I am currently trying to get the cars to loop but I am struggling to find a way to do it, please try and help me out with the code or point me in the right direction if you can please and thank you in advance

import flashx.textLayout.utils.CharacterUtil;

```
var result:Number = Math.random() * 100
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth
var background = new Background;
var char = new Char();
var car1 = new Car1();
var car2 = new Car2();
var car3 = new Car3();
var car4 = new Car4();


car1.x = Math.random()* stage.stageWidth;
car2.x = Math.random()* stage.stageWidth;
car3.x = Math.random()* stage.stageWidth;
car4.x = Math.random()* stage.stageWidth;
background.x = 200;
char.x = 700/2;

car1.y = -0;
car2.y = -150;
car3.y = -300;
car4.y = -450;
background.y = 200;
char.y = 450;

addChild(background);
addChild(char);
addChild(car1);
addChild(car2);
addChild(car3);
addChild(car4);

char.gotoAndStop("car");

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);

function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    car1.y +=12;
    car2.y +=12;
    car3.y +=12;
    car4.y +=12;
}


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_PressKeyToMove);

function fl_PressKeyToMove(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
switch (event.keyCode)
{
case Keyboard.RIGHT:
{
char.x += 15;
if (char.hitTestObject(barrier1))
{
char.x -=15 ;
}
break;
}
case Keyboard.LEFT:
{
char.x -= 15;
if (char.hitTestObject(barrier2))
{
char.x +=15 ;
}
break;
}
}
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, detectCollision);
function detectCollision(event:Event)  {

       if(char.hitTestObject(car1))
       {
       char.gotoAndStop("boom");
       }
       if(char.hitTestObject(car2))
       {
       char.gotoAndStop("boom");
       }
       if(char.hitTestObject(car3))
       {
       char.gotoAndStop("boom");
       }
       if(char.hitTestObject(car4))
       {
       char.gotoAndStop("boom");
       }

}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what you mean by loop? It looks like the cars will continue advancing to the bottom of the screen, are you wanting to reposition them at the top when they hit the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to get cars to reposition to the top of the screen as @onekidney guessed, you could easily do so by using the `%` operator:

```
function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    car1.y = (car1.y + 12) % stage.stageHeight;
    car2.y = (car2.y + 12) % stage.stageHeight;
    car3.y = (car3.y + 12) % stage.stageHeight;
    car4.y = (car4.y + 12) % stage.stageHeight;
}
```

You can read more about the modulo operator in the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00000678.html)